# How to analyze memory usage of a single process given a atop log file

Tags: linux, memory

I have several programs running on a server and they are causing some memory issue occasionally. so I used `atop` to log the memory usage on the server, and I am now trying to figure out when and which process is causing the problem, so I want to plot the memory usage of every interested process. however, i have no idea how to extract that.

now i have the atop log file and i know the PID of the interested process, how can i extract the memory usage of it during a certain period of time?